# How to push multiple values to a session array

Tags: php

I have a page which sets url parameters.  I want to store them in a session so that they are always in the shopping cart but the session gets overwritten and there is always only one item in the cart.

```
<?php
// Start the session - session was set in book details and/or library search page
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['title']) && $_GET['title'] !== ""){
    $_SESSION['name'] = array();
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    array_push($_SESSION['name'],$title);

}
```

Retrieving the session details

```
<?php 


foreach ($_SESSION['name'] as $key => $val) {
   echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this `$_SESSION['name'] = array();` create an empty array every time it's executed?

Comment: I don't think so.  I've tried it inside and outside of the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that it is re-declaring $_SESSION['name'] as a new array every time this code is run.

I suggest using something along the lines of:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['title']) && $_GET['title'] !== ""){
        if(!isset($_SESSION['name']) && !is_array($_SESSION['name'])){
            $_SESSION['name'] = array();
        }

        array_push($_SESSION['name'], $_GET['title']);
    }
?>
```

This does your previous check of seeing if $_GET['title'] is set, but then does another check to ensure if $_SESSION['name'] exists and is an array. If it's not an array it declares it.
The last thing it does is add your value to the array.

Comment: Not working - Thanks very much.  I see the logic in this - only if the session name hasn't been set an the session name is not a array will the array be set to empty however it's not working on my site.  I get a 500 error

Comment: Sorry I missed a ) please try it again

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know if it's my other code messing it up but it's adding the same item into the session twice now and still overwriting when I add another item.

Comment: Do you have other code that works with $_SESSION[‘name’]?

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the session name and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

push all value to an array(make it associative array) using array push method after that assign  that array in a session

Answer (score -1):

$ _SESSION is a superglobal array. Save the value in this field as follows:

```
 if (isset($_GET['title']) && $_GET['title'] !== ""){

$title = $_GET['title'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $title;

 }
```

Comment: That's going to end up the same way only one element, the "current" title.